# iOS13 Context Menu How to show or navigate to the current peeking view when tapping on it

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, contextmenu, ios13

I'm trying to implement "Context Menu" in iOS13 in a table view (tried collection view as well, they have same issue):

I followed the instruction [here](https://kylebashour.com/posts/ios-13-context-menus) , created a collection view with bunch of photos, and when 3d touch, I will get a preview with an action list, like this:

[Peek and Menu View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybW1k.jpg)

[Collection View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBIHi.jpg)

The delegate method in UITableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willCommitMenuWithAnimator:
(id<UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating>)animator;
```

and in collectionView

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willCommitMenuWithAnimator:
(id<UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating>)animator;
```

both don't have "`indexPath`";

So there is no way for me to pass in the current cell or index I'm peeking.

I want to implement this delegate method so when I tap on the preview image, it will navigate to the expected page with information that's bounded to the current cell.

What I want and tried is something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willCommitMenuWithAnimator animator: UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating) {
    animator.addAnimations {
        self.show(PreviewViewController(image: UIImage(named: "indexpathString")), sender: self)
    }
}
```

and the `indexpathString` is related to the current selected cell or collection so I can init the viewController based on it.

Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: A couple ideas were proposed here in this Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/steveshepard/status/1141499334376058881?s=20

Answer (score 13):

The function `contextMenuInteraction(_:willCommitWithAnimator:)` has been superseded by [`tableView(_:willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith:animator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/3375810-tableview), which provides the `UIContextMenuConfiguration` associated with the presented menu. At the point where your menu is presented, assign an identifier which will allow you to identify the row. The identifier should be any `NSCopying` object - e.g. an `NSIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    // Pass the indexPath as the identifier for the menu configuration
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSIndexPath, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
        // Empty menu for demonstration purposes
        return UIMenu(title: "", children: [])
    }
}
```

and then use that identifier in the `willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith:animator:` function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating) {
    guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? IndexPath else { return }

    // Use your index path to get your destination VC in some way; arbitrary example shown...
    let destinationVc = destinationViewController(for: indexPath)

    // Then animate the appearance of the VC with the provided animator
    animator.addAnimations {
        self.show(destinationVc, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: The configuration is omitted in Swift 5.1

Comment: I am getting a wrong random indexPath when i am trying to access  ==>   guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? IndexPath else { return }... What is the proper way to get the indexPath?

Answer (score 11):

There's a property in the `animator` called `previewViewController` that is of type `UIViewController?`. This is the same as the `previewProvider` you set in `tableView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt:point:)`, so if you set the `previewProvider` as your destination view controller, you can do something like this:

**Set your previewProvider**

```swift
override func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath,
    point: CGPoint
) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(
        identifier: nil,
        previewProvider: { () -> UIViewController? in
            let string = yourDataSource[indexPath.row]
            return PreviewViewController(image: UIImage(named: string))
        }
    )
    // actionProvider has a default value of nil, so you can omit it
}
```

**Use the animator to show it**

```swift
override func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView, 
    willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, 
    animator: UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating
) {
    guard let destinationViewController = animator.previewViewController else {
        return
    }

    animator.addAnimations {
        self.show(destinationViewController, sender: self)
    }
}
```